# JSSOR: Image is smaller than slide and should not be centered

Tags: jssor

first of all: GREAT STUFF!!

SITUATION: The image loaded in my slider are smaller than the slides container. Using "$FillMode: 5" I can make sure that images have the right size to display within the slides-container, but they are centered.

Q: Is there a way to have them align to the right, so that i can display the caption to the left of it.

TRIED: using CSS to align the image: neither

```
#slides img { float: left !important };
```

nor

```
#slides img {
     position: absolute !important;
     right: 0px !important;
}
```

did the job.

Answer (score 0):

A:
After some fiddling and around analyzing the actual sourcecode generated by the script i found out that

1. using #slides results in a coding error as the tag "" is duplicated (for whatever reason) and would therefor give 2 identical IDs, so better use ".slides" / ""
2. the following CSS does the job an aligns a smaller image to the right of the slide

   .slides {
     div {
       img {
         right: 0px !important;
         left: auto !important;
       }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Jssor slider will fill and align image (in following format) automatically according to $FillMode,

```
<img u="image" src="url" />
```

To fill image manually by your self, please remove u="image",

```
<img src="url" />
```